# Wireless camera for Convolutional Neural Networks

Tags: camera, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, gopro

Soon i will start working on a project that requires me to classify different objects using CNN (Convolutional Neural Networks) and track it using a drone. The camera i need should stream live video on FHD at @60. I searched a lot especially the go pro's camera but i didn't find anything related to how many frames during live stream. Hope you can suggest me some cameras.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a GoPro camera with a HDMI to USB capture card, this will give you 1080p 30 or 60 fps depending on the resolution and frame rate chosen. I'd look for a OpenMV Cam H7 if possible, the camera is designed for computer vision.

Comment: The HDMI to USB capture card will fix the streaming issue, but what about wireless streaming ??

Comment: @MohamedRabah there's no 1080@60 over WiFi with GoPro.